# After using .height() on parent div, child elements that change heights no longer effect the parent's height, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I have a parent div with some child divs.  Without doing anything to the parent div, if I invoke the following code on any of the children in the parent div:

`$('.child').height(newHeight);`

The parent div will conform to the new height based on all the heights of its children.

However, if I set the height on the parent like so:

`$("#parent").height(newParentHeight);`

And then change the height of any of the children in the same fashion as described above, the parent's height does not conform to the new height based on all the heights of its children.  Essentially, the parent's height is "locked" to the height I send it via the .height() method.

Is there a way to ensure the parent div will conform to the heights of all its children even if I set the parent's height using the code above?

UPDATE 1:
As requested, here is the CSS for the parent div:

```
#workarea
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your css for the parent div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.height()` is locking the div's height to whatever you specify, by directly setting the CSS style for the DOM element. You should explicitly unset the CSS style if you want it back to normal:

`$('#parent').css('height', '')`

Comment: Maybe better is to set `height` style to `auto`.

Comment: @VisioN, yes, that would work. I'm not sure however which one is more correct: adding an extra rule or just undoing what you'd done.

Comment: Yes, somehow. Anyway it does the job. +1

Comment: This worked, but as @VisionN mentioned, setting it to auto allowed dynamic height in the children to change the height of the parent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try, rather than using `height()`, to set a `min-height` on the element. With jQuery:

```
$("#parent").css("minHeight", "100px");
```

Might have some issues with older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`.height()` gives an explicit height to the element. Maybe in your case `.css('minHeight')` can help. (Consider cross-browser-compatibility when doing this).

```
.css('minHeight', newParentHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not set any height to parent div using CSS or jquery. Then set child height will change the parent height.

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/qhuMY/1/)

**NOTE** You can set height to child using jQuery CSS method i.e:

```
$('.child').css('height', 'some');
```

to resolve cross-browser issue